# How to set select default value from JSON object?

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm trying to create "update user" form for my site.

```
function get_value(id){

    $.ajax({

        url: '*censored*',

        type: 'get',

        data: {'id': id},

        success: function (json) {

 $('input[name=username]').val(json[0].user_name);
        $('select[name=language_id]').val(json[0].language_id).attr('selected','selected');
```

Not complete function, but I guess there's enough information. Setting existing values to input fields works, but how I can set default value for select? Above code I've tried.

Comment: default value what you mean? post the expected output also?

Comment: <p>Language</p>
        <select name="language" selected =??>
            <option value="aa">Klingon</option>
            <option value="bb">Quenya</option>
            <option value="cc">Wookiee language</option>
        </select>        'selected' should be the one which was set when profile was created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check each of the `options`, if their value equals your JSON-value:

```
$("select[name='language']").find("option").each(function() {  // Find all 'options' in your select
    if($(this).val() == json[0].language_id) {                 // Compare the value of the 'option' with your JSON-value
        $(this).attr("selected", "selected");                  // If this matches, set the selected="selected" attribute for the <option>
    }
});
```

In your HTML-code, you set the `selected`-Attribute for the `<select>`-Tag, which is wrong, you give this attribute to the `<option>`-Tag.

Aditionally, you put in the wrong `name`of the select: It's just `language`, not `language_id`.

Comment: Still not working. Should there be in html selected=something or what?

Comment: Yes, the selected `<option>`-Tag should have `selected="selected"` as an attribute. If this code doesn't work, please provide us your HTML-Code of the `<select>`-Tag, I think there could be a problem.

Comment: <select name="language" selected="selected" >
            <option value="fi">Finnish</option>
            <option value="en">English</option>
            <option value="sv">Swedish</option>
        </select>

Comment: Thanks and **ck my idiotism. Errors which doesn't give error messages suck.

Comment: No worries, we're all going trough this often :). Does it work now?

Comment: Yes, without problems.